# Select $k$ vertices from $n$ vertices such that no subset contains $1$ and $n$ and $1,n$

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

Let $p_n$ be a path with $n$ vertices.

I need the number of possible ways for to select $k$ vertices from $n$ vertices. such that:

- No two vertices are adjacent, and:
- Any subset of $k$ vertices contain vertex $1$ or $n$

Can you help me?

Comment: If they don't contain $1$ and $n$, then how can they contain $1,n$?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well then to be found is the number of distinct sums: $$a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_k=n-k$$ where the $a_i$ are positive integers.

That comes to the same as finding the number of distinct sums:$$b_0+b_1+\cdots+b_k=n-2k-1$$ where the $a_i$ are nonnegative integers.

With [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we find: $$\binom{n-k-1}{k}$$possibilities.